# Make left align colon clang-format in #pragma

Tags: clang-format

How can I always align colon to the left with clang-format.
I don't want it to be disable : 1234, but disable: 1234.

```
#pragma warning(disable: 1234)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Actually didn’t check it. Did you try clang 10 or trunk ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this.

SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon (Boolean) clang-format 7
If false, spaces will be removed before range-based for loop colon.

```
true:                                  false:
for (auto v : values) {}       vs.     for(auto v: values) {}
```

Comment: What if I want a different setting for pragma and for loop ?